# Error in unbeatable tic tac toe game

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to follow a book I purchased Python Programming for the absolute beginner 3rd edition. Chapter 6 Challenge 4, asks to make the game tic-tac-toe unbeatable. By amending the computer_move() function. I've amended it to make the game unbeatable (when the human player takes the opposite corners in the first two moves was the hole in the strategy). But I've now broken the part where the computer goes first. And I have no idea why.

I get the error
`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType`

```
# Tic-Tac-Toe
# Plays the game of tic-tac-toe against a human opponent

# global constants
X = "X"
O = "O"
EMPTY = " "
TIE = "TIE"
NUM_SQUARES = 9


def display_instruct():
    """Display game instructions."""  
    print(
    """
    Welcome to the greatest intellectual challenge of all time: Tic-Tac-Toe.  
    This will be a showdown between your human brain and my silicon processor.  

    You will make your move known by entering a number, 0 - 8.  The number 
    will correspond to the board position as illustrated:

                    0 | 1 | 2
                    ---------
                    3 | 4 | 5
                    ---------
                    6 | 7 | 8

    Prepare yourself, human.  The ultimate battle is about to begin. \n
    """
    )

def ask_yes_no(question):
    """Ask a yes or no question."""
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        response = input(question).lower()
    return response

def ask_number(question, low, high):
    """Ask for a number within a range."""
    response = None
    while response not in range(low, high):
        response = int(input(question))
    return response

def pieces():
    """Determine if player or computer goes first."""
    go_first = ask_yes_no("Do you require the first move? (y/n): ")
    if go_first == "y":
        print("\nThen take the first move.  You will need it.")
        human = X
        computer = O
    else:
        print("\nYour bravery will be your undoing... I will go first.")
        computer = X
        human = O
    return computer, human

def new_board():
    """Create new game board."""
    board = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        board.append(EMPTY)
    return board

def display_board(board):
    """Display game board on screen."""
    print("\n\t", board[0], "|", board[1], "|", board[2])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[3], "|", board[4], "|", board[5])
    print("\t", "---------")
    print("\t", board[6], "|", board[7], "|", board[8], "\n")

def legal_moves(board):
    """Create list of legal moves."""
    moves = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[square] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(square)
    return moves

def winner(board):
    """Determine the game winner."""
    WAYS_TO_WIN = ((0, 1, 2),
                   (3, 4, 5),
                   (6, 7, 8),
                   (0, 3, 6),
                   (1, 4, 7),
                   (2, 5, 8),
                   (0, 4, 8),
                   (2, 4, 6))

    for row in WAYS_TO_WIN:
        if board[row[0]] == board[row[1]] == board[row[2]] != EMPTY:
            winner = board[row[0]]
            return winner

    if EMPTY not in board:
        return TIE

    return None

def human_move(board, human):
    """Get human move."""  
    legal = legal_moves(board)
    move = None
    while move not in legal:
        move = ask_number("Where will you move? (0 - 8):", 0, NUM_SQUARES)
        if move not in legal:
            print("\nThat square is already occupied, foolish human.  Choose    another.\n")
    print("Fine...")
    return move

def computer_move(board, computer, human):
    """Make computer move."""
    # make a copy to work with since function will be changing list
    board = board[:]
    # the best positions to have, in order
    BEST_MOVES = (4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)
    #INCLUDED FOR CHALLENGE 4 CHAPTER 6 TO MAKE THE GAME UNBEATABLE
    SMART_HUMAN = ((2, 0), (6, 8))
    print("I shall take square number", end=" ")

    # if computer can win, take that move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = computer
        if winner(board) == computer:
            print(move)
            return move
        # done checking this move, undo it
        board[move] = EMPTY

    # if human can win, block that move
    for move in legal_moves(board):
        board[move] = human
        if winner(board) == human:
            print(move)
            return move
        # done checkin this move, undo it
        board[move] = EMPTY

    # since no one can win on next move, pick best open square
    for move in BEST_MOVES:
        if move in legal_moves(board):
            print(move)
            return move
    #EXTENDED FOR CHALLENGE 4 CHAPTER 6 TO MAKE THE GAME UNBEATABLE
        elif move not in legal_moves(board):
            for position in SMART_HUMAN:
                for move in position:
                    board[move] = computer
                    if move in legal_moves(board):
                        print (move)
                        return move



def next_turn(turn):
    """Switch turns."""
    if turn == X:
        return O
    else:
        return X


def congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human):
    """Congratulate the winner."""
    if the_winner != TIE:
        print(the_winner, "won!\n")
    else:
        print("It's a tie!\n")

    if the_winner == computer:
        print("As I predicted, human, I am triumphant once more.  \n" \
              "Proof that computers are superior to humans in all regards.")

    elif the_winner == human:
        print("No, no!  It cannot be!  Somehow you tricked me, human. \n" \
              "But never again!  I, the computer, so swear it!")

    elif the_winner == TIE:
        print("You were most lucky, human, and somehow managed to tie me.  \n" \
              "Celebrate today... for this is the best you will ever achieve.")

def main():
    display_instruct()
    computer, human = pieces()
    turn = X
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)

    while not winner(board):
        if turn == human:
            move = human_move(board, human)
            board[move] = human
        else:
            move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
            board[move] = computer
        display_board(board)
        turn = next_turn(turn)

    the_winner = winner(board)
    congrat_winner(the_winner, computer, human)

# start the program
main()
input("\n\nPress the enter key to quit.")
```

I'm not too sure where it is producing NoneType from, I've been working on it for quite a few days now, and I can't see the error. It's producing the error in the main function, but I haven't amended there and I wasn't supposed to.

I felt like I was really out of my depth with this, I think it's because I used tuples for the `SMART_HUMAN` I changed amending it to lists, but I get a similar error.

Any help would be really appreciated!

---

Edit: The full error I get is:

```
I shall take square number Traceback (most recent call last):
File "\chapter_6_challenge_4_computer_move_amended.py", line 217, in <module>
main()
File "\chapter_6_challenge_4_computer_move_amended.py", line 208, in main
board[move] = computer
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType
```

Comment: Look at the error's indicated line (which you should provide in your question - I'm not sure why you'd omit that), look at what it's trying to use as a `list` index, look at where that variable is coming from, look at how it gets assigned, figure out if there's any way it might get assigned `None` (there is), make it always assign an integer instead of `None`.

Comment: You do have the previous working version of the code safely under a version control system, don't you?  So you should be able to compare what worked with what doesn't.  Something you changed broke the code, so looking at the changes should help you deduce what did break.  (If you don't have the code under version control, please learn the lesson; make sure you do have code under version control so that you can go back to a known state, or compare your current code with earlier versions.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I don't think most people use version control until their company enforces it with an iron fist.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: only fools don't use version control; it allows you to get back to working code.  It allows you to make changes with confidence.  It allows you to compare working code with broken code.  It saves you having to retype the example from the book you're learning from.  Using a version control system has too many advantages for sane people not to use one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also likely people who are reading a book called "Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner". One step at a time. Condescension isn't a very effective learning tool.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - I'm not making an argument against version control; I'm reminding you that most people don't use version control unless they're forced to (and you just called them all crazy fools :P ).

Comment: I've been amending a saved copy, the error is coming from the main function. Line board[move] = computer, I've tried removing that from the function, but then the game becomes beatable again

Comment: If you know how to make changes without making mistakes, maybe you can afford not to use one.  If you don't, it is sensible to make sure you can get back to working code.  It might only be `tictactoe.py` copied to `tictactoe-v1.py` before you start making the changes — it is a primitive version control system.  But not being able to get back to working code is silly.

Comment: I've actually tried to run this and it works. Can you provide the exact steps (i.e. the values entered) that reproduce the error?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Once again, all I'm saying is that most people don't use version control. It's like Python 2's `range()` returning a `list`: that's bad and it shouldn't do that... but it does.

Comment: I've been doing something like that @JonathanLeffler I don't understand when the main is called it generates the error when the computer goes first, but it works fine when the player goes first. Is it that my list is too short?

Comment: @plamut, yes if you let the computer go first, then 0 > 7 > 5 generates the error

Comment: I think there are probably two problems.  One is that when the newly added `elif` clause loops finish, there's no return (or exit or whatever) after the loops, so the function returns None, when it shouldn't.  The second is that if the `elif` condition isn't satisfied, there isn't an `else` so the function again returns None when it shouldn't.  At the least, I'd put two print statements in the code to report if either of those return paths is executed (and although one print would be sufficient, it would be better to distinguish between the two).

Comment: @Trumble: If you've been working on a copy (and the `amended` in the file name suggests that), then you're OK — that's good enough (though I'd recommend RCS or Git or some formal VCS — even for learning code).  And you should compare the working code with the non-working code to make sure that you only made the changes you intended to make.  It allows you to localize your efforts — if the only change is where you intended it to be, then you only have to look at that code to work out what's wrong.  Code comparison is one basic technique for debugging (printing progress is another).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I will look at using Git. Thank you. I think I'm not exiting the loop properly as you've stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help on this one, it made me go back and rethink my approach, and here's the answer.

I had created two errors for myself, both solved from removing the SMART_HUMAN nested tuple. I was being too clever and got confused, by nesting the counter plays in a tuple, it was causing the error when the player played, I also had unnecessary lines. By removing the SMART_HUMAN nested tuple entirely and just adding an elif statement to play position 1 to counter the counter.

Here's the function now, the final for statement is the working solution. There's probably a better solution if it was a larger more complex game, but for the simple one it works :P

```
def computer_move(board, computer, human):
"""Make computer move."""
# make a copy to work with since function will be changing list
board = board[:]
# the best positions to have, in order
BEST_MOVES = (4, 0, 2, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7)

print("I shall take square number", end=" ")

# if computer can win, take that move
for move in legal_moves(board):
    board[move] = computer
    if winner(board) == computer:
        print(move)
        return move
    # done checking this move, undo it
    board[move] = EMPTY

# if human can win, block that move
for move in legal_moves(board):
    board[move] = human
    if winner(board) == human:
        print(move)
        return move
    # done checkin this move, undo it
    board[move] = EMPTY

# since no one can win on next move, pick best open square
for move in BEST_MOVES:
    if move in legal_moves(board):
        print(move)
        return move
#EXTENDED FOR CHALLENGE 4 CHAPTER 6 TO MAKE THE GAME UNBEATABLE
    elif move not in legal_moves(board):
        if BEST_MOVES[5] in legal_moves(board):
            print (BEST_MOVES[5])
            return BEST_MOVES[5]
```

My game is now unbeatable :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
move = computer_move(board, computer, human)
```

If `None` is returned (meaning that computer did not find any moves), the program exits with an error in the line that follows, because you need to provide an integer when retrieving an element from a list, but `None` is given instead.

There is either a bug in the `computer_move()` function, or, more likely, just a missing check for `None` - in the latter case, when the computer does not return a move, you should end the game, declaring a draw.

Comment: I hadn't thought about ending the game when a draw was the only outcome. I think I will try that approach thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, can we assume now that your question has been sufficiently answered?